# String Tokenization in Java

Tags: java, string

I have the following code

```
    System.out.println("Enter equation you want to calculate:");
    System.out.println("Equation can not have more than two variables");
    equation = input.next();

    StringTokenizer var = new StringTokenizer(equation,"");
    while (var.hasMoreElements())
    {
        System.out.println(var.nextToken());
    }
```

The user can enter equation like `A + B` or `Alpha + Beta`.
**I want the tokenizer to seperate the string like 
`Alpha`
`+`
`Beta`**

But the output I get is just the first element
`Alpha`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Anything wrong with `String#split()` on whitespace?

Comment: @ParagJadhav My Tokenization method is not separating the whole string equation. I have to separate `A+B` into `A` 
`+`
`C`

Comment: In your question you say that the input equation is in the form of `A + B`, not `A+B`.  What is your actual input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If your input is "Alpha + Beta" , then the below code results in 
Alpha
+
Beta



StringTokenizer var = new StringTokenizer("Alpha + Beta"," ");
            while (var.hasMoreElements())
            {
                System.out.println(var.nextToken());
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

`equation = input.next();` is only going to read the next (space delimited) word, not the entire equation.

Your problem isn't the tokenizer, it's that you're collecting your input incorrectly.

try instead:

```
equation = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of format A 'operator' B where 'operator' can mean any from `+-*/`, I'd suggest you to split with the regular expression. Demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6YbxZ1/2).

```
(\w+)([\+\-\*\/])(\w+)
```

I suggest you first to replace all the spaces to get rid of unnecessary mess. Also don't forget to escape with the double `\\`;

Let the input be: `String input = "Alpha + Beta";`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(\\+)(\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input.replace(" ",""));

String a = null;
String b = null;
String operator = null;

while (matcher.find()) {
    a = matcher.group(1);
    operator = matcher.group(2);
    b = matcher.group(3);
}
```

Will return `Alpha + Beta` from the variables `a`, `operator` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    System.out.println("Enter equation you want to calculate:");
    System.out.println("Equation can not have more than two variables");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String equation = input.nextLine();
    StringTokenizer var = new StringTokenizer(equation, " ");

    while (var.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(var.nextToken());
    }
```